# Fast pagination in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I remember doing `where ... limit 100000 200` is slow because mysql still scans through the first 100000 rows. It took many seconds (not milliseconds) to get rows past 1 million. Anyways I am in the design phase of a site. I'd like to do a search with multiple tags such as `cpp` `sockets`.

I'm trying to get quick searches. I think my options are to instead of use page # to use a timestamp (most likely as a 64bit int) or to have the lowest/highest row #. But I think I may need to go farther then that?

I'm thinking I need a lookup table, so if post 123456789 has the tags cpp socket howto i'd insert the post in a lookup table(lookupid, tagid, postid) with an index on tagid. Figure out which has the lowest count (do i use count(*) or update a row somewhere holding the current count?) then I could so my search with a statement like

```
select postid from Post p join
(select postid from tag_lookup where tag=@tag_with_lowest_count and post_id<@post_id_limit) 
  as t2 on p.id=t2.postid
//i'm not sure how to write a where that checks if a post has every tag in a list.
where @array_length_as_a_param == (select count(*) from tag where tag.postid=p.postid 
  and in @array //dapper probably handles this for me. Unsure if this is connrect
```

I have no data, tables, anything so I cant use `explain` yet (i'm semi bad reading it too). I'm brainstorming. So I'd use > or < depending if i am doing next/prev page and using a post_id rather then using page number.

Can anyone think of a nice and proper way of getting fast page lookups on random tags which i AND together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use `select count([your-primary-key])` instead of `*`.
2. use indices on the postid in tags and posts.
3. use a join instead of testing for equality in your where clause.

That's just from a cursory glance. Once you've done these three and if it's still not performant enough, post the results of an explain of the query and I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: Which where? I have 3. So this SEEMS like it would be fast and a good option to use?

Comment: :p I think its fast and a good option unless i go crazy on the fast side (make redis keep keys and completely rewrite many functions). But what about your point 3? all 3 of my where statements have equality test and i dont know which you are suggesting to join. I'm not even sure how i'd rewrite any of them

Comment: I'll have a solution for you when I have more bandwidth to spare on this.

Comment: o.O will it be time-consuming to implement? or give me brain damage? ok i guess. I look forward to if you have more bandwidth and want to spare on this. But try to keep it simple. I'm sure the above preforms fine, i just was wondering if this was bad design or a known good design